# SO Careers is using a local file path for app icon

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm not sure how this got there but on [this CV](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/ahsteele) the icon url for the `Blood Glucose Tracker` app is using `file://ssl.gstatic.com/android/market_images/web/favicon.ico`.

Wouldn't it also be better to use https instead of [protocol-relative urls](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/)?